# Can't read local geojson

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, stimulusjs

Trying to read a geojson in Rail. Specifically

/public/switzerland.geojson

Console error:

```
Started GET "/oladvancedview" for ::1 at 2023-02-02 16:42:44 -0800
Processing by DemoController#oladvancedview as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering demo/oladvancedview.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered demo/oladvancedview.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 160)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 3.0ms | Allocations: 2803)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.7ms | Allocations: 3039)


Started GET "/Users/gscar/Documents/Ruby/RailsTrials/os-stimulus-mapping/public/switzerland.geojson" for ::1 at 2023-02-02 16:42:44 -0800

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/Users/gscar/Documents/Ruby/RailsTrials/os-stimulus-mapping/public/switzerland.geojson"):
```

`rails routes`

```
 public_switzerland GET  /public/switzerland(.:format)       public#switzerland {:format=>"json"}
```

routes.rb `get 'public/switzerland', defaults: { format: 'json' }`

xx.html.erb `<% path = File.join Rails.root, 'public', 'switzerland.geojson' %`

Passing with Stimulus

```
    <div id="avmap"
        data-controller="ol-advanced-view" 
            data-ol-advanced-view-target="avmap" 
            data-ol-advanced-view-url-value = "<%= path %>" 
            style="height:400px" >
    </div>
```

No Javascript errors in stimulus controller.

Clueless what is going on. How do I read this file? Thank you for any ideas?

Comment: What is it that you're actually trying to do here? If you're trying to link to a static file located in your public directory you don't need or want a route as rails (or your http server depending on how its configured) will serve static files from the public directory. The file is available to the browser as `/switzerland.geojson`.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline

Comment: Thank you. I certainly tried that, but am being confused because my Stimulus controller isn't working right and the I thought the file was missing. That's another problem.